# Client/Server program doesn't run in regular way

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, arduino, server

this client server program runs only once, the android send string to server and server forward it to arduino. when I send first time the arduino got it but when I send a second time server receive it but doesn't forward it to arduino. I cannot see the problem. I appreciate if someone can help me..

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
public class server {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    String type1;
    String type;
    Socket socket;
    Socket s;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    private ClientHandler c = new ClientHandler();
    private Connection con = new Connection();

    public server(int port) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            new Connection().start();
            // new ClientHandler().start();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    private class Connection extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            //Socket socket;      
            while (true) {
                try {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    // DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    System.out.println("connected");
                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    type = dis.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("jag fick det från android: " + type);

                    new ClientHandler().start();
                    dis.close();
                    //c.run();      
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }
    }

    private class ClientHandler extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            //System.out.println("1");
            try {
                //   System.out.println("2");
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                // System.out.println("3");
                System.out.println("got it");
                dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (true) {
                try {

                    if (type == null) {
                        //break;
                        continue;
                    }
                    // System.out.println("4");
                    //DataInputStream dis1 = new     DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                    //type1 = dis1.readUTF();
                    //System.out.println("3");

                    dos.writeUTF(type);
                    System.out.println("jag fick det från ardunio: " + type);
                    //dos.flush();
                    //dos.close();
                    // con.run();
                    // type = null;
                    //socket.close();
                    break;
                    //continue;
                } catch (IOException e2) {}
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new server(3389);
        System.out.println(" Server startar");
    }
}
```

Comment: Begin by not swallowing the exceptions... if something is raising an exception you should at least know that the exception was raised, try printing them at the very least.

Comment: Lord Jesus that indentation ... xD

Comment: I cannot see the edit i don't know why can u send it to me plz?

Answer (score 0):

You're only reading from the socket once. `ClientHandler` should do all the I/O, in its loop: none of it should be done in the accept loop.

NB `Connection` is a poor name for an accept-loop class. You don't need it as a data member. The Socket and the input and output streams should be members of `ClientHandler`, not of `server`.

Comment: u mean that i move the streams and socket for both clients to own class?

Comment: There is no 'mean' about it. I *said* that `ClientHandler` should do all the I/O, and that the socket and its input and output streams should be members of `ClientHandler`, not of `server`. You're just asking me to repeat myself.